# sort values from a dictionary/json file

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I've got this discord.py command that makes a leaderboard from a json

[image]

cogs/coins.json (the dictionary) looks like this:

```
{
  "781524858026590218": {
        "name": "kvbot test platform",
        "total_coins": 129,
        "data": {
            "564050979079585803": {
                "name": "Bluesheep33",
                "coins": 127
            },
            "528647474596937733": {
                "name": "ACAT_",
                "coins": 2
            }
}
```

(The green strings with numbers in the json files are discord guild/member ids)

How do I make the code shorter and clearer?

Thanks for helping in advance, because I really don't know the solution

Comment: Do not add images, copy and paste your code

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do? state it clearly in your post and paste the relevant code only.

Comment: This question makes me want to paste an image into comments as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to finding (sorting) the first ten items within a dict, then the way is much easier than repeatedly going through the dict and doing different things there.

And little better code, like `Dict.get` for safety access.

Based on a sample of JSON data.

```py
with open('cogs/coins.json', 'r') as f:
    coins_data = json.load(f)

# Get is safefy access to dict
# Dict.items() returns pairs of (Key, Val)
members_coins = list(coins_data.get(str(ctx.guild.id), None)['data'].items())

if members_coins is None:  # If data not found
    await ctx.send('Not data')
    return

# Sort list by Val part of pair, and `coins` key, reverse for descending
members_coins.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]['coins'], reverse=True)

output = ''
# list[:10] for first 10 items (if list is smaller, thats okay, python don't mind)
for member_id, vals in members_coins[:10]:
    output += f'{vals["name"]}: {vals["coins"]}'
    # output += f'<@{member_id}>: {vals["coins"]}'  # If you want "mention" display of user

await ctx.send(output)
```